# $3$ people are dealt $5$ random cards from a deck of $52$. What's the probability that at least someone gets exactly $2$ aces?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> $3$ people are dealt $5$ random cards from a deck of $52$. What's the probability that at least someone gets exactly y$2$ aces?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455890/probability-question-with-deck-of-cards-three-players-5-cards-each-pat-leas) is an equivalent question, but I'm wondering about solving it with inclusion-exclusion. Let:

$$S=\{\text{dealings of 5 cards from 52 to 3 people}\}$$
$$A=\{s\in S:\text{player A is dealt 2 aces}\}$$
$$B=\{s\in S:\text{player B is dealt 2 aces}\}$$
$$C=\{s\in S:\text{player B is dealt 2 aces}\}$$

Then our answer will be:
$$P(A\cup B\cup C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C)-P(B\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap C)$$
$$=3P(A)-3P(A\cap B)$$
$$=\frac{3\dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{48}{3}}{\dbinom{52}{5}}-\frac{3\dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{48}{3}\dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{45}{3}}{\dbinom{52}{5}\dbinom{47}{5}}$$

Is this correct? It seems to match the other answers in the equivalent question linked above, I was just wondering about inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed a critical word in the question, $3$ people are dealt $5$ random cards **each**...

Your answer then  is correct, though I'd have been inclined to do the inclusion-exclusion just considering disposition of aces

$$3*\dfrac{\binom52\binom{47}2 - \binom52\binom52} {\binom{52}4}$$

Comment: I like this more, a lot simpler

Comment: Glad you like it ! $\;\;$ :)